# tkinter only displays top of label text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, raspberry-pi3

I am making an alarm clock radio using python3, tkinter on a raspberry pi 3 using a 2.8in PiTFT. And I am using a true type font called digital-7. When I create a tkinter Label to hold the time, then only the top 3/4s of the text is displayed. If I add a "\n", then the full text displays. I've done a lot of searching but haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: time displayed correctly]

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.configure(background='black')

# make root use full screen
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))

# using 2.8 PiTFT with 320x240 display

timeText = tk.StringVar()
# digital-7 is a true type font, which shows clock in 7 segment display
timeLabel = tk.Label(root, font=('digital-7', 120), fg='red', bg='black', textvariable=timeText, anchor='n')
timeLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=6)

def updateDate():  
    global timeText

    dt = datetime.datetime.now()

    # without the '\n' the bottom part of the time gets cropped
    tts = dt.strftime('%H:%M')
    timeText.set(tts+'\n')

    root.after(2000, updateDate)

updateDate()

root.mainloop()
```

The full code is here (it is still a work in progress):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dumbo25/tkinter-alarm-clock-radio-gui/master/acr.py

digital-7 goes in /home/pi/.fonts and here is where I got digital 7 from:

https://github.com/dec/angular-canvas-gauge/blob/master/Sample/fonts/digital-7-mono.ttf

Comment: Your question is how to remove the '\n'?

Comment: What happens if you use a different font? It would help if the first step is to narrow the problem down -- does it happen just with that font or with all fonts?

Comment: Unrelated: but I have bad news for you. The Pi does not include an RTC, so it can't keep time when it's off. It needs to connect to the internet to get the current time when it boots, or you need to attach an external RTC.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're stating that _this code_ produces a label that only shows 3/4 of the text?

Comment: Yes, how do I remove the "\n" and still see the full character on the time.

Comment: Other fonts work fine. The date and HH:MM are Arial.

Comment: I would like to use the space below the time to display the song playing.

Comment: I did measure the height of the label and it returned 92 instead of 120

Comment: At Novel, An RTC is not required. Plus or minus a few seconds is okay. ntp is fine to keep the time close enough for a alarm.

Comment: adding:

    timeLabel.configure(pady=30)

helps but does not quite fix the issue. I lose 30 above the time, but I am able to squeeze in the title of the song playing under the time. I tried pady=(0,30), but it doesn't work the 30 is ignored and zero pad is applied.